# SQL return values from year to date (YTD)

Tags: mysql

How to get values from year to date ?I need to display 2 values from ytd current year and previous year without changing query in future. As i undertand, ytd starts from first day of January. For example; from '2018-01-01' until current month of the year, and another query will be for ytd previous year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE DATE > DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y/1/1') AND DATE < NOW();
```

For this Y2D and:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE DATE > (SELECT DATE_FORMAT((SELECT date_sub(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y/1/1'), interval 1 year) AND DATE < (SELECT DATE_FORMAT((SELECT date_sub(NOW(), interval 1 year);
```

For last years Y2d

Comment: Thx, the current ytd works fine, but for last year ytd somehow not works.